# How to write 10k for 10000 with the siunitx package?

Tags: siunitx

In some fields of science (e.g. computer science) large numbers without units are often abbreviated using the kilo prefix. Is there a way to do this using the `siunitx` package?

Examples:

```
After 21k iterations, the loop was terminated.
```

I tried:

```
\num{21\kilo}
\SI{21}{\kilo}
```

However, both give me errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @Mico Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your typesetting objective. E.g., are you simply asking how to write, say, `\SI{10}{\kilo\joule}` or `\SI{100}{\kilo\meter}`, or are you asking for advice on how to instruct the `siunitx` package to typeset `\num{10000}` as `10k`?

Comment: @mico Thanks for the quick response. I'd like to achieve the latter. I tried to clarify my question.

Comment: `After $10^4$ iterations`

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the alternative, but that's not what I'm asking for. :-) For 10000 I'd actually prefer your solution. However, for e.g. 21000 ```$21 \cdot 10^3$``` is a little cumbersome. I edited my question to make that clearer. Also, in the context of ```siunitx```, I think ```\num{21e3}``` would be better.

Comment: @Nos What's the problem in being clear and write 21000?

Comment: @egreg That's no problem. However, I'd like to be consistent with other publications in the field that use the 21k notation.

Comment: It depends on *how* it is used. If the “k” immediately follows the number, just write `$21\mathrm{k}$`, it's not a job for `siunitx`.

Comment: @egreg I thought it might be a job for ```siunitx```, since I use it to handle my other numbers and would like to have a consistent solution.

Comment: @Nos Well, “21k” is inconsistent with everything to begin with, IMHO.

Comment: @egreg Maybe, but I think it could (and maybe should) still be possible.

Comment: What's wrong with simply `21k`?

Comment: @PeterWilson Thanks for the suggestion. However, I have a rhetorical question: What is wrong with ```10 m``` instead of ```\SI{10}{\meter} ``` :-) ? In principal, nothing. Still, I would prefer to let ```siunitx``` take care of all the styling of my numbers.

Comment: @Nos the spacing between `10 m` and `\SI{10}{\meter}` is quite different --- it's smaller in the case of the measurement units. This is way you like it more ;-)

Comment: @Rmano Thanks for pointing that out. That was exactly my point. I think it is better to let ```siunitx``` handle these details than having to handle them myself. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to define k as a unit:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\k{k}

\begin{document}
After \SI{21}{\k} iterations, the loop was terminated.

\end{document}
```

However, this seems a bit hacky and I'm not sure, whether the spacing between the number and the k is correct.

**EDIT:** Since it seems to be preferable, here is an alternative with no space between the number and the k. I also added a macro (thanks to @Fran), to increase readability:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = ]\k{k}
\def\n#1k{\SI{#1}{\k}}

\begin{document}
After \SI{10}{\k} iterations, the loop was terminated.

After \n10k iterations, the loop was terminated.
\end{document}
```

Ultimately, it would be nice to have this functionality included in `siunitx` as a variant of the `\num` command. Therefore, I opened an issue with this feature request at Github ([link](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/378)). We'll see how that works out. If it is actually implemented, I will update this answer.

Answer (score 4):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

When people use expressions such as

```
I ran a 5k race last week.
```

or

```
After 21k iterations, the loop was terminated.
```

their intent is *in no way* to imbue the terms `5k` and `21k` with any kind of scientific precision and exactitude. Instead, the intent is informal and situational. In the former case, it's shorthand for saying, "I ran a five kilometer race last week"; listeners will hopefully be in no doubt about the unstated length parameter. In the latter case, it's shorthand for "After 21000 iterations, the loop was terminated."

Either way, trying to adduce the heavy machinery of the `siunitx` package -- specifically, the package's `\num` and `\SI` macros -- to typeset such informal expressions seems misguided. For sure, if one had to spell out the shorthand locution in the first sentence, one would write either "I ran a five kilometer race last week" or "I ran a 5 kilometer race last week" -- but *surely not* "I ran a `\SI{5}{\kilo\meter}` race last week".

I suppose one can quibble about whether or not it's desirable to insert a thinspace between the number and the letter `k` in the terms `5k` and `21k`. (I agree that a interword space seems excessive.) I'm pretty sure that with or without the thinspace, nobody will be confused about the meaning of the terms. Because the expressions are informal shorthands and because of the lack of potential for confusion, I'd choose the simpler solution and *omit* the thinspaces.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I like the arguments that you make. However, this answer does not strictly answer the question. Also, you base your argumentation on the assumption that the ```k``` notation is only used in informal contexts, which is IMHO not the case (see e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06870)). Perhaps it _should_ only be used in informal texts, but that's highly subjective.

Comment: @Nos I read “5 fps” (with a normal space) and ”200nm” (no space) on page 2, “160k iterations” (no space) on page 4. They use “fps” as an acronym, which is fine, but it should be opened up at first usage in the document body, otherwise it is apparently considered a unit, so it should be separated from the number by a thin space. The unit nm *must* be separated with a thin space. The “k” is just a shorthand for “000”. Keep it attached to the number, no space.

Comment: @egreg You're absolutely right. It is a little sloppy. However, I would still not call it informal. And I think 2669 citations agree. :-) Many comments and answers in this thread give advice on how to best write ```21k```. And I appreciate it, but frankly speaking: I don't want to know. :-) That's exactly the reason why I love Latex and packages like ```siunitx```. Because they are so great at taking care of these questions, so that I don't have to deal with them. Hence my question about a ```siunitx``` way of writing ```21k```.

Comment: @Nos - My apologies for not defining explicitly what I mean by "informal". I certainly don't see it as a synonym for "sloppy" or "careless". Maybe the word "casual" is closer to what I had in mind. As @egreg has pointed out in a comment, the paper you hold up as an example does *not* do a good job of typesetting items such as `200ms` (p. 2) carefully, i.e., according to SI-mandated typesetting standards. The authors' use of `k` in the context of `number of iterations` is fine. Their use of `M` in `(300M)` on p. 10 is far more problematic; if I had been the editor, I wouldn't have let it pass!

Comment: @Mico No need to apologize! After all you, and everybody else here, are helping people like me. OT: I totally agree with you. And that is the downside to arxiv, there is no editor. :-) Still, the mentioned paper is a great publication.

Comment: I agree with @mico here: I think that when you say 5k and 21k you mean a number, not a number with a unity, like "I run a five thousand yesterday". So my vote is to type it without any space, as part of the number.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
After \SI{21}{\kilo{}} iterations, the loop was terminated.
\end{document}
```

Note, however, that the result is exactly the same that use `21\,k` (...as `\SI{10}{\meter}` is also equal that `10\,m`), that is easy to type, and more readable in the source document.

I use `siunitx` often, but is it not a mandatory way to type units in LaTeX, it is only a tool to be used only if it helps.

Comment: Thanks. This does actually answer my question. The reason why I always try to use ```siunitx``` for numbers and units is to enforce consistency. Readability is no concern for me. I can read it in the beautifully rendered PDF if I want to. TBH, I had hoped more for the existence of a ```\num``` version (e.g. ```\num{21k}```). That way it would be readable and enforce consistency.

Comment: @Nos Well, this is a  macro language, nothing prevents you to define some as `\def\n#1k{\SI{#1}{\kilo{}}}`and then use  `\n21534536k` or `\n{21534536}k` or `\n 21534536 k`  or `\n 21 534 536 k` or even  `\n 21 53 45 36 k`... In any case is readable, will produce the desired result whatever the spaces used (of course, except in `\n{21534536} k `)  and will use `siunitx` consistently.